# Background Picture on a Responsive Website doesn't fit when the screen size changes

Tags: css, html, background, positioning

How can I get the background of a Responsive website to adapt and move with the rest of the content on the Website?

My background is split doesn't cover the entire background, only partially to create an effect where each sides are of a different color (gray).

However, when I change the size of the screen, all of the elements will be moved and the background will not be positioned as it was initially.

How could I go about making sure that no matter what the size of the window is, the "gray bars" will always fit with main content?

If you look at this picture, this is how it should look like:

Also here is the script for the background image as well as the site wrapping:

```
.gray {background:url(http://frenchegg.com/images/gray.png) no-repeat; height:100%;}
.lgr {background-size:85% 100%; background-position:center;}
.main-content p {
    color:#555;
}

.site-wrap {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
}
```

You can find the website [here.](http://frenchegg.com)

[image: website]

Comment: I checked the link. It is already working as you desired!

Comment: Have you tried to change the size of the window? You will see how the elements are popping out of the white part of the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you're page may need a little restructuring, but I believe I have a solution for you.

Initially, the main problem stems from background size being set to percentage widths (note background-size is a css3 property and not fully supported... but thats another issue).

For a proof of concept and for you to see what you're going to have to change, try to following:

- Remove the background on 'gray' (line 1880 in styles.css)
- Apply inline rules to 'row' (NOT TO THE ROW RULE) on line 230 in the source so it looks like the following:

  ```
      <div class="main-content">

          <div class="row" style="
              padding: 65px;
              background: url(http://frenchegg.com/images/gray.png) no-repeat;
              background-size: 85% 100%; background-position: center;">
  ```

The rules are as follows for copying purposes.

```
    padding: 65px;
    background: url(http://frenchegg.com/images/gray.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 85% 100%;
    background-position: center;
```

Note the padding is a bit screwy, but it's simply to show you where your background needs to be to respond correctly.

Cheers mate,

GW

Comment: Oh right! You're awesome!! Thank you! However I'm not quite sure how to make it cover the upper and lower part. Do you have any clue?

Comment: How do you mean mate? It's looking good with your changes now?! Is there anything else i can help with?

Comment: Oh I found a way! :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Oh well while you are here haha! If you look down, you will see a graphic where it says "Latest Lesson" that graphic has basically the same kind of issue... When I change the size of the screen it doesn't fit properly anymore.